# Difficulties with Ocaml. Lists

Tags: list, ocaml

I wrote this function which was supposed to give me the before last element of a list, but it doesn't work? Do you know why? thanks!

`let rec exo1= match l with
  |List.length l = 0 or 1 -> failwith exo1
  |List.length l > 2  -> List.tl l in exo1 l
  |List.length l = 2 -> List.hd l ;;`

Comment: Why not match the list instead of the list length?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below.. I commented out the answer.

```
let rec exo1 lst =
match lst with
| [] -> failwith "List is too short!"
(*| (*the magic happens here*) -> (*ans*)*)
| hd::tl -> exo1 tl
```

Answer (score 0):

In OCaml `match` exists to *match* on the structure of a value using patterns. You have provided boolean expressions rather than patterns to match against.

If you wish to use `List.length` then you simply want to use conditional expressions.

```
let rec exo1 lst =
  if List.length lst = 0 || List.length lst = 1 then
    failwith "Too short!"
  else if List.length lst = 2 then
    List.hd lst
  else
    exo1 (List.tl lst)
```

But this is inefficient because `List.length` has to iterate over the entire list to compute its value, and we don't really need to know that.  We could compute it just once and store that value:

```
let rec exo1 lst =
  let len = List.length lst in
  if len = 0 || len = 1 then
    failwith "Too short!"
  else if len = 2 then
    List.hd lst
  else
    exo1 (List.tl lst)
```

But better is to properly use pattern-matching to handle the cases the list has zero or one elements, where it has two, and where it has more than two elements.

```
let rec exo1 lst =
  match lst with
  | [] | [_] -> failwith "Too short!"
  | [x; _] -> x
  | _::xs -> exo1 xs
```

Which can be abbreviated using the `function` keyword.

```
let rec exo1 = function
  | [] | [_] -> failwith "Too short!"
  | [x; _] -> x
  | _::xs -> exo1 xs
```

A few other issues:

- In a boolean expression, `or` should be `||`, and `List.length l = 1 || 2` would be parsed as `(List.length l = 1) || 2`. As `2` is not a boolean value, this would fail to compile.
- You try to match against `l`, but that name is unbound. You likely meant to write `let rec exo1 l = ...`
- Your `exo1` function is never recursively called.